# Why do we use "des" in “Ce ne sont pas des touristes”?

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation

If we want to write “Those are not tourists” in French.
Why is it written as follows (with des)?

> Ce ne sont pas des touristes.

And, NOT as follows (with de) as it would be in any other negative sentence?

> Ce ne sont pas de touristes.

Comment: Le verbe *être* semble être une exception. Des relents d'un cas nominatif en latin ou d'un cas sujet en ancien français ?

Comment: Pourtant, je dirais _Ce ne sont pas **de** simples touristes_

Comment: @okiharaherbst: Oui, mais c'est dû à une règle différente. C'est l'adjectif qui change la donne, il transforme le *des* en *de* sans qu'il n'y ait besoin de négation et même lorsqu'il s'agit d'un sujet ou d'un complément introduit par une préposition.

Comment: @Simplicity Could you specify your point about « as it would be in any other negative sentence? »? Can you give examples of other negative sentences? Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

The usage is to replace "***des***" by "***de***" in the negative form when expressing an absence (zero vs some).

> Il n'y a pas **de** touristes, [il n'y a personne].
>
> Il n'a pas **de** frères.

On the other hand, when opposing two statements, even if the second one in not expressed, "***des***" is kept. With "***être***", the opposition is implicit:

> Ce ne sont pas **des** touristes [mais des professionnels].
>
> Il n'a pas **des** frères, mais **un** frère.

---

L'usage est de transformer « **des** » en « **de** » dans la tournure négative quand il s'agit de signifier une absence :

> Il n'y a pas **de** touristes, [ il n'y a personne ].
>
> Il n'a pas **de** frères.

En revanche, quand il s'agit d'une opposition, même sous-entendue, on conserve « **des** ». Avec « **être** », cette opposition est implicite :

> Ce ne sont pas **des** touristes [mais des professionnels].
>
> Il n'a pas **des** frères, mais **un** frère.

---

Ref.:

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_en_fran%C3%A7ais#N.C3.A9gation_et_partitif

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3514

Comment: Bon, bonus, mais par défaut. Je trouve qu'il manque des informations, en particulier sur le cas de « de simples touristes ».

Comment: @Gilles « Ce ne sont pas de simples touristes » est la négation de « Ce sont de simples touristes ». Cette expression n'est en conséquence pas sujette à la règle que j'évoque dans ma réponse à la question posée qui concerne la négation de « des », pas celle de « de ».

Comment: @Mistalis La règle « il n'y a pas = 0 -> pas de pluriel » n'existe pas. Le pluriel est possible ici. http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/accord-avec-pas-de-et-sans-a3757232

Answer (score 1):

Similar uses of 'être' include, for example, 'on n'est (nous ne sommes) pas des sauvages'.

The emphasis is on 'what we are not' (savages, tourists) rather than an expression of zero quantity. As Grévisse's notes indicate, an indefinite rather than a partitive plural.

Comment: Could you explicitly quote the relevant excerpt from the Grevisse (if short enough)?

Comment: I don't have my copy to hand, I'm afraid, but will try to post a reference later. Consider the difference between 'Nous n' avons pas de clients ' and ' Nous ne sommes pas des clients, nous sommes des amis du patron '... (sorry for the erroneous spaces; phone keyboard is misbehaving!)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the `de` is used to talk about quantity.

> Il n'y a pas **de** touriste.

Just like :

> Il y a beaucoup **de** touristes.

Here, the `des` is about quality.

> Ce ne sont pas **des** touristes.

But the example with `simple` :

> Ce ne sont pas **de** simples touristes.

makes me wonder if the `simple` adjective is the cause of the `de` or if there is another reason.

Answer (score 0):

You DE not DES with plurals in 3 cases:

- quantity e.g. beaucoup DE filles
- when there is an adjective directly following e.g. il y a DE moderne maisons
  (the adjective comes before if it relates to BAGS:
  Beauty -beau.
  Age -moderne.
  Goodness -super.
  Size -petit.)
- with negatives il n y a pas DE pommes
  (unless this is to say it IS something else (even if this is not directly stated) For example:
  Qui?
  Ce ne sont pas DES garcons [c'est les filles]

Answer (score -3):

Because 'des' is plural:

> "The plural indefinite article des refers to more than one countable
>   thing in an indefinite sense.
>
> Il a des livres intéressants.    He has some interesting books.
>
> J'ai acheté des chaussettes.    I bought some socks."

http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/de-vs-du-de-la-des_2.htm

Comment: This question is about negatives, not plurals.

Comment: It is negative and plural: touristes vs touriste.

Comment: The asker knew the rule about « de » in the negative, but didn't understand the exception with « être ».  Your answer doesn't refer to the negative at all.

Answer (score -5):

because touristes is plural. and des is an article for plural nouns.

Comment: Yet we would say “ce ne sont pas de simples touristes” or “je ne vois pas de touristes”.

Comment: Again, in French there is a rule about the negative and the usage of « de ». This question is about the exception to the rule which uses « être ».