# Je ne [verb] pas (de/le/les) after negative?

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation

I have the sentence: *Je n'aimais pas (les/des/de) légumes et je refusais d'en manger.*

I was taught in French class to use 'de' after a negative always.

I asked one of my friends who was French, he corrected it to 'les'. Now I'm confused... Please help :)

Comment: I'll let someone with more knowledge than I have give you a full answer, but I think this is to do with `generality`, so you need to use the `definite article` - *I did not like vegetables (in general)*. However,  `de` is used in the negative in place of the `indefinite` and `partitive` article (e.g. du, de la, une, un etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was taught in French class to use 'de' after a negative always.

You were taught wrong or you learned the rule wrong. The rule is: replace an *indefinite* article, such as *un,* *une* or *des,* with *de* in a negative sentence. (There are some possible exceptions to this, as described [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9542), but it's generally a good guide.) A definite article, such as *le, la* or *les,* remains the same in a negative sentence. You cannot replace it with *de*; that would change the meaning.

Your friend suggested using *les* here simply because in French the definite article is used to refer to things in general. "Vegetables" in English translates to "les  légumes" in French. See the answers to the following question for more information about using the definite article after the verb *aimer*: [La difference entre « j'aime le fromage » et « j'aime du fromage »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/la-difference-entre-jaime-le-fromage-et-jaime-du-fromage) (The difference is that the first is correct, and the second isn't)

Comment: j'aime du fromage?? J'aimerais du fromage (I'd like some cheese). wrong is not an adverb....

Comment: @Lambie: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean with the first two sentences of your comment. I think the answers and comments at the linked post explain both that "J'aime du fromage" is wrong and that "j'aimerais du fromage" is right. I am using "wrong" as an adverb in the first sense defined here: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wrong

Comment: Ok, then I would have said that. When a person says A as compared to B, it sounds like both are  right but they are different. Whereas here, as you say, one is right and one is wrong. No worries.

Answer (score 3):

In general, “pas de” is used.

Examples:

1. Je ne bois pas de jus d'orange. *I do not drink orange juice*.
2. Nous n'achetons pas de chaussures. *We are not buying shoes.*

Preference verbs (aimer, préférer, détester, adorer) ALWAYS use definite article (la/le/les/l’) BOTH in positive and negative constructions.

Examples:

1. J'adore la bibliothéque. *I love the library.*
2. Elle n'aime pas les lapins. *She does not like rabbits.*
3. Tu ne préfères pas la nuit. *He does not prefer night.*

Answer (score 2):

Je n'aime pas les légumes. I don't like vegetables. That is a general statement and in French you have to use the definite article.

As a general rule and without going into every way to use de, des, de la and d', these partitive prepositions are used to express some, any or an s.

Would you like **some cake**? Voulez-vous **DU gateau**?[literally, some of this cake]. Non, je ne veux pas de gateau. [I don't want cake or any cake].

So, there is a **regular negative sentence**: Je *n'aime pas* les légumes.
versus: I ate **some** vegetables. J'ai mangé des légumes. [some vegetables or some of the vegetables or just vegetables, it depends on the context].

Answer (score 1):

1- du, de la, des, quelques, un peu de... sont utilisés pour faire allusion à une quantité concrète de quelque chose que l'on PRESENTE. Je veux dire quelque chose dont on présente le NOM.

Je te sers de la soupe?

Du chocolat, tu en veux?

Je t'ai acheté des mouchoirs.

Il y avait quelques enfants à la soirée.

2- On REPREND après une négation ce qui a été PRESENTE auparavant pour en dire autre chose.Il n'y a plus alors aucune allusion à une quantité quelle qu'elle soit.

Je ne veux pas DE soupe, merci.

Je ne mange jamais DE chocolat.

Je n'ai pas besoin DE mouchoirs.

Tu rêves! Il n'y avait pas D'enfants à la soirée.

3- On peut aussi dire:

Je n'aime pas LA soupe. Il s'agit alors de parler de la soupe en général.

Non, merci. Je déteste LE chocolat. Il s'agit ici aussi du chocolat en général.