# When not to use 'de' in negative expressions?

Tags: grammaire, articles, adjectifs-indefinis

I am having trouble understanding the usage of the indefinite article in the following sentences.

(i) *On n'a que de**s** problèmes avec cette machine*

(ii) *Goûte ça : c'est du cheval ! Ce n'est pas **du** bœuf.*

My understanding was that we do not use *de* in negative expressions. Is there something here I am missing?

Comment: We **do** use "use ***de*** in negative expressions". The rule is roughly that: we do not use the indefinite article (*un, une*) in negative sentences,  *un* and *une* become *de* or *d'* (in front of a vowel or mute h) after a negative expression (ne...pas / ne...jamais / ne...plus ... etc.).  There is no indefinite article in any of your sentences, ***des*** (standing for *de les* and ***du*** (standing for *de le*) are partitive articles. I suggest you visit the two answers to [this question about the use of *de* in negative sentences](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23146/358).